# Bug? Can't finish Most Wanted 10 race

Tags: need-for-speed-most-wanted-2012

On the PS3 version (with the newest patch), I cannot unlock Most Wanted car 10 (Alfa Romeo 4C Concept). I have won the race 10+ times. Each time, the slow motion "Most Wanted car defeated - shut it down to own it screen" shows. After that, the Most Wanted car crashes into a roadblock just past the end of the race, and gets stuck there. I can ram it many times, and nothing happens. If the most wanted car does get through the roadblock, I chase it up the hill, and it drives off the cliff into the ocean. The car never reappears to chase me. (That's what's supposed to happen, and I've had it happen with other Most wanted cars).

When I look in Easy Drive, the Most Wanted 10 race still shows as incomplete, and I can restart it, but have the same issues every time. Has anyone else run into this problem, and is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Most Wanted car eventually got caught up in the roadblock instead of driving off the cliff, and I was able to take it out. It probably took 20+ tries before this happened though. Must be a bug!

Comment: It is a bug. I never faced this issues with the PC version.